# send email with php in a local host

Tags: php, email, xampp

I want to send email with php using xampp.

```
<html>
   <head>

   </head>
   <body>

   <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
    $to = $_POST['email_add'];
    //define the subject of the email
    $subject = $_POST['sbjct']; 
    //define the message to be sent. Each line should be separated with \n
    $message = $_POST['msg']; 
    //define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n
    $headers = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\nReply-To: webmaster@example.com";


    $mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
    echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
    ?>
    <form action="send_email.php" method="post">
    Email Add<input type="text" name="email_add" />
    Subject<input type="text" name="sbjct" /> <br>
     <textarea name="msg" rows="9"  cols="20"></textarea><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
    </form>

    </body>

    </html>
```

It's not working. Is there something wrong with my code?

I found some tutorials on the cloud, but it mentions SMTP and I do not understand it.

Comment: Change `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);` to `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and remove the `@` from `@mail()`. You'll likely need to setup authenticated SMTP.

Comment: you can use mercury mail server in xammp.

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't actually send the email... in Linux it'll forward it to *sendmail* or similar daemon, in Windows it'll forward it to an *SMTP server*.  Depending on your OS you have to setup these other processes and explain to PHP how/where to contact them (in php.ini in the `[mail function]` section).

Answer (score 1):

PHP need a SMTP server to send emails.

You can specify it in your php config file (and set it to your ISP one for example), or use "Test Mail Server Tool" ( http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/ ) that catches the smtp local calls and saves them in a directory of your hard disk, so that you can debug everything.

Obviously, this solution works only if you need to **debug** it.
If your need is to **send** the mail, please refer to php documentation and use your ISP SMTP server.

Comment: +1. I never had this problem with XAMPP on Win/XP, but when I switched to Windows 7 it was missing a local smtp server. Installed a test smtp server, and all was good.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the mail() function on Windows from a local development environment, you may need to specify an SMTP server that can relay the mail for you. Linux has this functionality baked in, Windows may not. Your ISP may provide you with this or a webmail provider may allow you to relay mail through them.

Look inside your php.ini file and locate the [mail] section and fill in:

> SMTP = smtp.yourprovider.com
>
> SMTP_PORT = 25

From the PHP mail manpage

"The Windows implementation of mail() differs in many ways from the Unix implementation. First, it doesn't use a local binary for composing messages but only operates on direct sockets which means a MTA is needed listening on a network socket (which can either on the localhost or a remote machine)."

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <html>
  <head>

   </head>
  <body>


<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
Email Add<input type="text" name="email_add" />
Subject<input type="text" name="sbjct" /> <br>
 <textarea name="msg" rows="9"  cols="20"></textarea><br>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>

</body>

</html>

 <?php
    If(isset('submit'))
 {
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   $to = $_POST['email_add'];
   //define the subject of the email
   $subject = $_POST['sbjct']; 
   //define the message to be sent. Each line should be separated with \n
    $message = $_POST['msg']; 
    //define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n
    $headers = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\nReply-To: webmaster@example.com";


$mail_sent = mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";

  }
      ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script I re-use in a lot of my projects, pretty straight forward just copy in and change the obvious values.

```
$email_to = "myemail@gmail.com,anotheremail@gmail.com";
        $email_subject = "This is the subject line";

        $break = 'echo "/n"';

        $form_email = "no-reply@myemail.com";

        //Function to convert /n to line breaks in HTML
        function nl2br2($email_message) {
           $string = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "<br />", $string);
           return $email_message;
        }

        //Unformatted email body
        $email_message = "This is the main blody of the email";

        //Format string against function
        nl2br2($email_message);

        // create email headers
        $headers = 'From: '.$form_email."\r\n".
            'Reply-To: '.$form_email."\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```